# javascript not letting me use modulu? %?

Tags: javascript, typescript, modulo

I am trying to find if a number is divisible by 3 --- and I was trying to use this % after researching a bit, however I am getting this error...

```
script.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %
```

which seems to say I cant use it? That doesn't make sense to me, why would I not be able to use it?

```
numArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100];

function startBingBong(){
for each (num in numArray){
if (num % 3 == 0){
console.log("Bing");
} else if (num % 5 == 0){
console.log("Bong");
} else if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0){
console.log("Bing Bong");
} else { console.log(num)}
}};
```

Comment: why the tag `typescript`?

Comment: im using typescript to write it. wasn't sure if that was a factor.

Comment: basically you have an each to much, and you iterating over the keys of the object and use it as value instead of using the item of the array. neverthe less, using `for ... in` should be avoided with arrays, because it iterates over other custom properties as well. better use a for with an index with start value, check and incrementor part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `for each`syntax you're using is incorrect. The correct way to write it in Javascript (EcmaScript 5) is:

```
for(var i=0;i<numArray;i++){
    var num = numArray[i];
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using ES6, you could use the following:

```
for(let num of numArray){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such syntax in JavaScript `for each (num in numArray){`.

To iterate over all elements of array you can use `Array.prototype.forEach`. You must pass a function called iteratee. It will be invoked for every element in array.

```
var array = [1,2,3];
array.forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(el);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct javascript. `for each (num in numArray){` See: [For loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) You cannot use `num % 3` as num is not anything. Use `arrayName[position] % 3`. You should also put the strictest `if statement` first.

```js
var numArray = [12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

function startBingBong(){
for (var i =0; i < numArray.length; i++){
if (numArray[i] % 3 == 0 && numArray[i] % 5 == 0){
console.log("Bing Bong");
} else if (numArray[i] % 5 == 0){
console.log("Bong");
} else if (numArray[i] % 3 == 0){
console.log("Bing");
} else { console.log(numArray[i])}
}};

startBingBong();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what you are looking at. The simplest way of doing what you want is like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        console.log("Bing");
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        console.log("Bong");
    } else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
        console.log("Bing Bong");
    } else {
        console.log(i)
    }
}
```